# NSString stringwithstring and stringwithformat difference

Tags: iphone, xcode, string, nsstring, openal

I am really confused any help will be highly appreciated

So what is the difference below

```
int myInteger = 1;
myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"anotesound%i",myInteger];
```

and this

```
myString = [NSString stringWithString:@"anotesound1"];
```

I thought both should be same but open al do not accept those are equal, it works for the stringwithstring but not works for stringwithformat

Comment: how does it not work?  compiler error or crash or what does your result string look like?  Have you tried `myString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"anotesound%d",myInteger];` ?

Comment: Those will output the same thing "anotesound1". Not sure what your question is.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",myString); gives the same output that is what i am hitting my head to the wall for 2 hours. Also i try with %d not working...                   I have a class Sound manager and at that class on this line NSNumber *numVal = [soundLibrary objectForKey:aSoundKey]; EXC_BAD_ACCESS error occurs. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

stringWithFormat: always returns a newly created and autoreleased object, which will eventually be released and become a zombie.  stringWithString: in this case returns the literal (constant) object itself, which will never been released.

I'd recommend you to learn the memory management of iOS, or use ARC.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/

Answer (score 0):

The results are the same, the error is elsewhere.

The difference is in wether or not myInteger is a constant or fill change on different instantiations. If it is always the same just use:

`myString = @"anotesound1";`

There is no need for the `stringWithString` method when the string is a constant.

Comment: Thank you anyway still not figure it out.

Comment: string is not constant, it is changed by a switch 1 or 2

Comment: Run the Analyzer and turn on NSZombies. The difference in code it just changing timings enough to cause the bug to appear.

Comment: Thank you so much it found a zombie. An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0xf37d820. Now what should i do?